# mysql command with Symfony Process

Tags: mysql, symfony

I want to execute an mysql command to simple import an SQL file with Symfony Process.
Because the chars "<" and ">" are not supported by Symfony Process, I was able to create the SQL file with mysqldump and option "--result-file" instead of ">".

Question now: how can I import this SQL file with mysql command?
Is there an equivalent for "result-file" for the "<" ? Something like "source-file" ?

What I tried:

```
$process = new Process([
    'mysql',
    '--host=localhost',
    '--port=3306',
    '--user=root',
    '--password=root',
    'database_name',
    '<',
    'sqlDump.sql'
]);

$process->run();
```

But this will result in error because Symfony Process escapes all parts of the command with quotes and then tries to execute the following command:

```
exec 'nice' '-10' 'mysql' '--host=localhost' '--port=3306' '--user=root' '--password=root' 'database_name' '<' 'sqlDump.sql'
```

Comment: Please share more details about what you've tried so far, and where you are stuck

Comment: `mysql ... -e "SOURCE /path/script.sql"`. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_execute

Comment: @Nico Haase view my edit

Answer (score -1):

Here an alternative to import your dump:

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

$mysqlUserOption = '--user=root';
$mysqlPasswordOption = "--password=root";
$mysqlHostOption = "--host=127.0.0.1";
$mysqlPortOption = "--port=3306";
$mysqlDbOption = 'database_name';

$subCommand = "mysql $mysqlUserOption $mysqlPasswordOption $mysqlHostOption $mysqlPortOption $mysqlDbOption < sqlDump.sql";
$command = [
     'bash',
     '-c',
     $subCommand,
];

$process = new Process($command);

$process->run();
```

Your error is probably not the one you mentioned, you can find the error with:

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;

if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
    throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
}
```

Comment: You forgot to share how to resolve the problem

Comment: Why is the first part of your answer relevant? OP already found out why the "command" failed - "*because Symfony Process escapes all parts of the command with quotes"*"

Comment: I have to kindly disagree with the part about the problem not being that Symfony escapes redirection operators. That's the whole point of parametrised arguments. What OP really wanted was to feed standard input for the command. Apparently Symfony has some [support](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html#using-php-streams-as-the-standard-input-of-a-process) for that but, in fairness, I don't know if it can be used for this use case or if it can be done in a performant way (SQL dumps can be huge and we don't want them loaded in RAM).

Comment: A little correction about my previous comment. Process constructor accepts an `InputStream` as argument. Again, I don't know if that will work.

Comment: Thanks for intel @ÁlvaroGonzález I will try that!